# log json string message using log4j in JSON format without breaking the format with quotes

Tags: logging, serialization, properties, log4j, special-characters

I am trying to format logs in a json format and using pattern layout to do so. But the output getting generated is not in a proper json format because of the extra quotes within a msg is getting logged.

Below is the log4j.properties file
=======================log4j.properties==================

```
appender.file.layout.pattern={"level":"%p","time":"%d{ISO8601}","thread":"%t","file":"%F", "line":"%L","message":"%m"}%n
loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.ibm
logger.file.level = error
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Below is the coding format

```java
String msg = "!@#$%^&*()_+=~{}[]|<>?;'Text with special character /\"\'\b\f\t\r\n";
// to escape especial character, serializing msg with jackson library method
Serialize serializeMsg = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(msg);
String jsonString = "" + serializeMsg + "\", \"crn\":\"" + crn + "\", \"otherProperty\":\"" + crn + "\"";
log.debug(serializeMsg );
```

Json log generated

```json
{"level":"DEBUG","time":"2021-12-20T20:05:14,465","thread":"main","file":"App.java", "line":"81","message":""!@#$%^&*()_+=~{}[]|<>?;'Text with special character /\"'\b\f\t\r\n"", "crn":"5741af48-808a-4e55-8f37-681f025b1ce3", "otherProperty":"5741af48-808a-4e55-8f37-681f025b1ce3""}
```

How can I remove extra quotes from the message? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly: `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(msg)` outputs a valid JSON, therefore it is a string enclosed in double quotes. The message you constructed in your code is:

```
"!@#$%^&*()_+=~{}[]|<>?;'Text with special character /\"'\b\f\t\r\n"", "crn":"5741af48-808a-4e55-8f37-681f025b1ce3", "otherProperty":"5741af48-808a-4e55-8f37-681f025b1ce3"
```

and your `PatternLayout` encloses it in another pair of double quotes (`"%m"`). You can easily remove some double quotes from your code to make it a valid JSON message.

However the whole approach you took to solve your main problem (formatting log messages as JSON) is unstable (it's a big hack): you require all log messages in your application to have a JSON-resembling format. What happens if you forget to format a message correctly? What about library messages that certainly don't follow your format? What happens if your application's user want to change the logging layout? Your approach might also be vulnerable to [log injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Log_Injection) if you are not careful about what you are logging.

A standard approach would be to let Log4j format your messages as JSON. There is a [JSON Template Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) for that. You just need to:

1. Add the [`log4j-layout-template-json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-layout-template-json) to your dependencies,
2. Create in your applications classpath a template (let's call it `logTemplate.json`):

   ```json
   {
       "level": {
           "$resolver": "level",
           "field": "name"
       },
       "time": {
           "$resolver": "timestamp"
       },
       "thread": {
           "$resolver": "thread",
           "field": "name"
       },
       "file": {
           "$resolver": "source",
           "field": "fileName"
       },
       "line": {
           "$resolver": "source",
           "field": "lineNumber"
       },
       "message": {
           "$resolver": "message",
           "stringified": true
       }
   }
   ```
3. Update your `log4j2.properties` file to use the JSON Template Layout:

   ```
   appender.file.layout.type=JsonTemplateLayout
   appender.file.layout.eventTemplateUri=classpath:logTemplate.json
   appender.file.layout.locationInfoEnabled=true
   ```
4. Log messages by simply calling:

   ```java
   log.debug("!@#$%^&*()_+=~{}[]|<>?;'Text with special character /\"\'\b\f\t\r\n");
   ```

Comment: thanks for answering the question and also suggesting a better approach to resolve the problem. Actually client may not allow us to add any further dependency for now, so unfortunately might have to go with the solution of removing the quotes from the code itself which I did and now I am getting an output in a valid json format. Thanks again for the suggestions.

Comment: surely will update to json template layout due to all those security concern which you described earlier. Accepting your comment as an answer.